# why can't I pass the data as json using Ajax and Jquery to the php side?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

```
function delete_user(email)
{

    //if(confirm("Do you want to remove this user with mail id: "+email))
    //{ 
        var z = {email : email}

        console.log(z)
        $.ajax({
        url: "delete_user.php",
        type: 'POST',
        data: z,

        success: function (data) {


            console.log(data);
            return false;
            var i=0;
            var element = "<table style='border-collapse: collapse;'>"
            while(data[i] != null)
            {

                element = element + "<tr style='height:15px' onmouseover='rowbig(this)' onmouseout='rowsmall(this)'><td>"+data[i].fname+"&nbsp"+data[i].lname+"</td><td>"+data[i].email+"</td><td>"+data[i].dob+"</td><td><button onclick='delete_user(\""+data[i].email+"\")'><img src='delete.png' style='height:20px;width:20px'/></button></td></tr>";               
                i++;
            }
            element = element + "</table>";


            $("#response").html( element );



        },
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false
    });
    //}

}


<?php 

    header("Content-Type:application/json");
         $email ="";

         function test_input($data) {
          $data = trim($data);
          $data = stripslashes($data);
          $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
          return $data;
        }
        function deliver_res($status_message,$result)
             {
                header("$status_message");


                $response['status_message']=$status_message;
                $response['result']=$result;

                $json_response=json_encode ($response);
                echo $json_response;
             }


             $servername = 'localhost';
             $username = 'root';
             $password = '';
             $dbname = 'webdata';
             $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

            if(isset($_POST['email']))
            {
                $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);

            }
            else
            {

                deliver_res("name not received","false");
                exit();

            }


            $sqll="DELETE FROM admindata WHERE email='".$email."';";
            $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sqll);


             $return_arr = array();

            $sqll="SELECT * FROM admindata ORDER BY id DESC ;";
            $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sqll);


            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) 
            {
                $row_array['fname'] = $row['fname'];
                $row_array['lname'] = $row['lname'];
                $row_array['email'] = $row['email'];
                $row_array['dob'] = $row['dob'];

                array_push($return_arr,$row_array);
            }

            echo json_encode($return_arr);

            echo "\n";

    mysqli_close($conn);






?>
```

I just can't seem to pass the data as JSON using AJAX and Jquery to the PHP side. Is there anything anything wrong with the syntax?

Comment: Maybe it is the PHP part where you are not handling stuff correctly?

Comment: Why are you setting `contentType:false`?

Comment: Use a `post` alias of `ajax`: `$.post('delete_user.php', z).done(function (data) {}).fail(function (error) {})`

Comment: @MysterX sure that's simpler but is only a wrapper for `$.ajax` which should also work fine and doesn't solve any problems

Comment: have you tried `dataType: json`? also your php script would be useful to see :)

Comment: What do you mean by _"pass the data as JSON"_? Send your data as a application/json request body, instead of as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`? If so PHP does not be default handle JSON request bodies. You would have to manually parse `php://input`

Comment: @PatrickEvans also have to stringify the data being sent to do that and set contentType

Comment: I did.. but to no use.

Comment: here is my updated code

function delete_user(email)
{
 
 //if(confirm("Do you want to remove this user with mail id: "+email))
 //{ 
  var z = {email : email}
  formdata=JSON.stringify(z)
  console.log(formdata)
  $.ajax({
        url: "delete_user.php",
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: formdata,

Comment: Don't dump code into comment blocks. Update the question with it so it can be formatted properly and read by all

Comment: @MysterX I changed the datatype to JSON..

Comment: @charlietfl I have checked the php using Servistate on Chrome. It is working just fine

Comment: @charlietfl I'm so sorry.. I'm new here

Comment: No problem..can [edit question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44887609/edit) at any time with any updates

Comment: why are you echoing a newline (\n) character in PHP after your echoed JSON? Pretty sure that will corrupt the response as far as jQuery ajax is concerned. Also your SQL is vulnerable to injection attacks - you should read up on how to use parameterised queries and prepared statements to protect your data from malicious attempts to interfere with or steal it.

Comment: @ADyson can you tell me more about how I can do away with the injection attacks? Well, I thought I bypassed that possibility in the function 'test_input' by making use of HTML special charecters.

Comment: @charlietfl can you suggest me all the changes that should be made to my jquery and ajax part?

Comment: @GourabChattopadhyay htmlspecialchars gets rid of HTML markup which might help prevent _script_ injection, but does not really help with _SQL_ injection. http://bobby-tables.com/ contains both a humorous but accurate look at how an attack can happen, and also some good advice on preventing it. The PHP section shows you how to use prepared statements and parameters to pass variables into your query, which is the most important aspect of defending against these types of problems. You can also find dozens of similar examples online if you google it.